# Windows API Mousehook , Capture rightmousebutton + Ctrl (WM_RBUTTONDOWN + MK_CONTROL) clicked togather

Tags: winapi, ui-automation, keyboard-hook, mouse-hook

initially i was able to print something when i pressed only right mouse button using
`if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)`but now , i want the same effect, i want to print something when right mouse button + **Ctrl** key is pressed. how can i acheive that ?

i have tried this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow::mouseProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        auto& ms = *(const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (pMouseStruct != nullptr)
        {
            if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN & MK_CONTROL)  // Here, i added MK_CONTROL but it doesn't work
            {
                qDebug() << "Print something when Right mouse button and Ctrl button is pressed togather"; 
            }
        }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, Code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

**UPDATE**

when i want to try the case where only Ctrl is pressed and it should print something, it still doesn't work

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow::mouseProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        auto& ms = *(const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (pMouseStruct != nullptr)
        {
            if (wParam == MK_CONTROL)  // Here, i added only MK_CONTROL but it doesn't work
            {
                qDebug() << "Print something when  Ctrl button is pressed ";
            }
        }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, Code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

what am i missing here ?

Comment: *when I want to try the case where only Ctrl is pressed and it should print something, it still doesn't work* You only registered the mouse hook, to hook the ctrl key, you also need to register the keyboard hook(`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`).

Comment: `if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN & MK_CONTROL)` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT, actually my mouseProc function prints the name/text of UI element where the cursor is pointing at, it is created by using this `mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, &mouseProc, hInstance, 0);`  so in this sensitive situation , how can i introduce a keyboard hook  + mouse hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to capture the right button + ctrl, you can check the state of the Ctrl key (whether it is pressed) when `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` is detected.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK mouseProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    auto& ms = *(const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (pMouseStruct != nullptr)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN && (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL)&0x8000))  //Left CONTROL key as example
        {
            std::cout << "ctrl + rbutton";
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, Code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

If you want to use a keyboard hook to hook **only** "Ctrl":

```
LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* pKeyboardStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (pKeyboardStruct != nullptr)
    {
        if (pKeyboardStruct->vkCode == VK_LCONTROL)  
        {
            if(wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
                std::cout << "  -ctrl-  ";
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, Code, wParam, lParam);
}
void main(void)
{
    HHOOK hmouse = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, hInstance, 0);
    HHOOK hkeyboard = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardProc, hInstance, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hmouse);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hkeyboard);

    return;
};
```